# Integral identity (with maybe a bit of Fourier)

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Let $\mu$ a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$.

I came accross the following identity : $$\int \int \exp \big( -\frac{\left| x-y\right|^2 }{2t}\big)d\mu(x)d\mu(y)= \sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left| \int e^{i\lambda x}d\mu(x) \right|^2 e^{-\frac{t\lambda^2}{2} }d\lambda  .$$

But I can't figure it out. I recognize that $\left| \int e^{i\lambda x}d\mu(x) \right|^2  = \hat{\mu}(\lambda)^2$ which is the Fourier transform of the measure $\mu$.

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start on the right. Since $d\mu$, $\lambda$ and $x$ are real,
$$ \left| \int e^{i\lambda x} d\mu(x) \right|^2 = \int \int e^{i\lambda(x-y)} \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y). $$
Now include the outer integral and interchange the order of integration via Fubini's theorem:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}} \int_{\lambda=-\infty}^{\infty} \left| \int e^{i\lambda x} d\mu(x) \right|^2 e^{-t\lambda^2/2} \, d\lambda = \int \int \left( \sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}}\int_{\lambda=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\lambda(x-y)-t\lambda^2/2} \, d\lambda \right) d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y). $$
The inner integral is now done in the usual way by completing the square, shifting the contour back to the real axis and using the Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-tk^2/2} \, dk = \sqrt{2\pi/t} $ and the result follows.